# How can I pull data from MS SQL using Python (pyodbc) faster (increase speed of performance)?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I want to increase the speed in which I pull data from MS SQL using python. The table I pull has a little over 100k rows and 10 columns. I know it's a big dataset, but is there some sort of functionality, code or parameter I can set to increase the speed in which the data is retrieved?

I do not have a problem with getting the data, I just have an issue with getting it faster.

The normal code I use to pull data is the following:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
con = pyodbc.connect('connection_string')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,con)
```

Note: The data is stored locally in MS SQL

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the steps you have taken to try and determine where the bottleneck is. For example, if the database is on a remote server have you done any tests to investigate whether the bandwidth of the network connection is limiting the rate at which you can retrieve the results?

Comment: That's not a big dataset, but it's also not much information in your question.  There are loads of things you can do to speed up MSSQL fetching data, but no-one can help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: I have provided the code. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the query.  There are a few possibilities.  **Query execution** may be slow if you are filtering on non-indexed columns.  **Data manipulation** may be slow if you are doing calculations in the query.   **Data transmission** may be slow just because you have a lot of data moving across the network.  You should show the query, and possibly the table layout.